# How to track DFP data (revenues, impressions, etc.) according to Google Analytics UTM values

Tags: google-analytics, google-dfp

I'm looking for a way to integrate all my DFP data (impressions, CTR, revenues, etc.) to my Google Analytics campaigns (and sources, medium, etc.).
From what I understand [Google Analytics premium/360 has a feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6371469?hl=en) which integrates with DFP data but I also see that [it costs (at least) $150K/year](http://www.actualmetrics.com/google-analytics-price/) which is a bit over my budget right now :)

It seems like a pretty common issue so I think I'm not the first one to need a functionality like that.
Otherwise what are my option to track if a specific marketing campaign is yielding the expected revenues ?

Thanks !